# ¿Cómo obtener el id del usuario logueado en Laravel pero desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Necesito deshabilitar unos botones según el usuario logueado y para eso necesito compararlo con el usuario logueado y quiero hacerlo desde JS, tienen idea de cómo?.
Intenté mediante una variable pero no me detecta el campo:
var userID = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}";

Answer (score 0):

Si estás trabajando en un archivo con extensión .js, no podrás utilizar la funcion php de laravel para que te retorne el ID del usuario, es decir  {{Auth::user()->id}}

Si estás trabajando en un archivo con extensión php, entonces si debería funcionarte eso. Pruebalo y nos cuentas. Te lo digo porque tuve el mismo problema hace unos días y era por eso.